# Aurelia Routing- Reloading the Web Site with F5 results in wrong bundle URLs when using Webpack Dev Server

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I'm new to Aurelia and stuck at setting up routing with `pushState` options properly. I have two routes (one for a list view, one for a details view). When I load up http://localhost:8080, the bundles are correctly loaded:

[image: Navigation via http://localhost:8080]

However, when I simply press F5 to reload the page with `http://localhost:8080/applicants/1` being the current URL in the address bar, then the bundles are not loaded properly because now `applicants` is part of the bundle URL:

[image: Error while loading bundles]

My router configuration looks like this:

```js
import { RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';
import { PLATFORM } from "aurelia-framework";

export class App {
    
    configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration): void {

        config.options.pushState = true;
        config.options.root = '/';
        config.map([
            {
                route: '',
                name: 'applicants',
                moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./applicant-list/applicant-list'),
                title: 'Applicants'
            },
            {
                route: 'applicants/:id',
                name: 'applicant-detail',
                moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./applicant-detail/applicant-detail'),
                title: "Applicant Detail"
            }
        ]);
    }
}
```

The list view simply uses regular HTML tags for navigation:

```html
<template>
    <h1>Applicant List</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/applicants/1">Applicant 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/applicants/2">Applicant 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

The implementation of the detail view should not matter, but here it is anyway:

```js
export class ApplicantList {

    id: number;

    activate(queryParameters: { id: number }): void {
        this.id = queryParameters.id;
    }
    
}
```

I could not find anything useful about this, neither in the [Aurelia Routing Documentation](https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration), nor in their [Contact Manager Tutorial](https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager). It works properly when I switch to hash-based routing.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after writing this question, I realized that the HTML meta tag `base` is not configured by the Aurelia CLI. To fix it, go to the `webpack.config.js` and search for the line containing `const baseUrl = ''`. This should be changed to `const baseUrl = '/'`. You'll probably have to restart the Webpack Dev Server for this to take effect (`npm run start` or `yarn start`).